# Next and Preview image with dynamic url

Tags: php, mysql, image

I made a very simple image gallery, with a Next and Preview button. My content is generated dynamicly so i have dynamic URLS

```
<a href="content.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'] -1; ?>" ><div id="next">Next </div></a>
<a href="content.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'] +1; ?>" ><div id="prev">Prev </div></a>
```

Everything is work fine, but when I hit the "Next" button on my last image or the preview button on my first image, I got a blank page, beacause there are no more records in the database. So i need an IF statement.

Example: If (no more records)  echo 'error' else echo 'some message'

Thank you

Comment: It is difficult to write the condition without more information. Do you have any function to count the number of rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="content.php?id=<?php
 $maxValue =6; //Enter Limit here
 If (($row['id'] - 1) < maxValue){
 echo $row['id'] - 1;}
?>" ><div id="next">Next </div></a>
```

I do not know if this makes sense to you. I hope I understood your question. I did not see another answer. If its not let me know and I will delete my response by adding a note to your question.

Also as:

```
<a href="content.php?id=<?php $maxValue =6; If (($row['id'] - 1) < maxValue){ echo $row['id'] - 1;} ?>" ><div id="next">Next </div></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

its not clear that from where your id is coming. are you getting this from database?
But one thing is clear that when you click on Next on last image then the value passed will have no related image.
For preview problem please check the value $row[id].